# Pandas: Dataframe from ftp file

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, ftp

I want to put the contents of a big tab-separated text file, that I retrieve via ftp, directly into a pandas dataframe.

```
import pandas as pd
import urllib.request as ur

# retrieve only the header column & set dtype to save some memory
refseq_summary = "ftp://ftp.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/genomes/refseq/assembly_summary_refseq.txt"
req = ur.Request(refseq_summary)
z_f = ur.urlopen(req)
col_names = pd.read_csv(z_f, sep='\t', nrows=0, skiprows=1)

for col in list(col_names.columns[:]):
    col_names[col] = col_names[col].astype("object")
col_names["taxid"]= col_names["taxid"].astype("Int64")
col_names.rename(columns={'# assembly_accession':'assembly_accession'}, inplace=True)
col_dtypes = col_names.dtypes.to_dict()
col_names_list = list(col_names.columns.values)

# read the whole file, and set the dtype & column names
df = pd.read_csv(z_f, sep='\t', dtype=col_dtypes, names=col_names_list, comment="#")
```

But for some reason the first ~850 lines are missing in `df`, and the first row is totally messed up.

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that the return value of `urlopen` is not a plain file but a stream so it can only be read once. So after the first `read_csv`:

```
col_names = pd.read_csv(z_f, sep='\t', nrows=0, skiprows=1)
```

you have already read a part of the stream - that part is unspecified and depends on the implementation of `read_csv`.

So on second read:

```
df = pd.read_csv(z_f, sep='\t', dtype=col_dtypes, names=col_names_list, comment="#")
```

You do not start at the beginning of the file but where the first read stopped, hence the missing lines and the messed up first row.

Unfortunately, I know no simple workaround, so IMHO you have only 2 simple ways:

- write the stream on a temporary file that you will erase after processing. As you now have a true file you will be able to open it as many times as you need
- process the stream in one single pass - but you will have to change a lot of things in your code